# Eliminar outliers de varias columnas en R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Tengo un df que solo contiene columnas con valores cuantitativos. Necesito eliminar, para cada columnas, los outliers. He mirado diversos tutoriales pero no encuentro ninguna que reproduzca esto de forma masiva en todas las columnas a la vez.

Gracias.

Comment: El tema outliers da para escribir al menos un capitulo de un libro, ¿dónde estaría tu problema? ¿En identificarlos? ¿En aplicar algún criterio a varias columnas? Si es esto último, te sugiero que edites la pregunta y agregues la forma en que los estarías identificando. Saludos.

Comment: En realidad, lo que quiero hacer es un pca a partir de diversas variables cuantitativas. El pca se ve muy afectado por la presencia de outliers. Así que primero quería eliminarlos en cada una de las variables que introduzco en el análisis pca. Ese es el motivo. Esperaba que hubiese alguna función sencilla para ello en vez de tener que montarla yo